# Determine redirect destination using AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, redirect

Is there an AJAX-y way to find out the destination of given URL that redirects?

Use case: use inputs a short url, and this javascript (without leaving the page) informs the user of the destination URL.

Thanks.